# image in mapkit iphone

Tags: ios, mapkit

I am a newbie to mapkit. I followed a tutorial and used that code in my project.

I want to display an image instead of pin, and that image is in resources folder.
How am I supposed to get that in there?

Thanks

Code so far:

`viewDidLoad` method of `NewMapViewController`:

```
MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center.latitude=/*latitude*/;
region.center.longitude=/*longitude*/;
region.span.longitudeDelta=0.01;
region.span.latitudeDelta=0.01;
[mapview setRegion:region animated:YES];
MapAnnotation *ann=[[MapAnnotation alloc]init];
ann.title=@"MLeaf";
ann.subtitle=@"Headquarters";
ann.coordinate=region.center;
[mapview addAnnotation:ann];

MapAnnotationView *ann1=[[MapAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:ann reuseIdentifier:YES];
ann1.canShowCallout=YES;
ann1.img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"eg.png"];
```

I have initialized title and subtitle in MapAnnotation and have initialized canShowCallout and img in MapAnnotationView

Is this correct way? My app crashes because of `NSInvalidArgumentException` on the line where I initialize MapAnnotationView in viewdidload.

Comment: When people give you useful answers to your questions, please upvote the answers, or **accept** them, using the little icons to the left of each answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [How do I add custom pins to the iPhone MapKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699171/how-do-i-add-custom-pins-to-the-iphone-mapkit) and [iOS MapKit custom pins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145797/ios-mapkit-custom-pins). Mainly, you have to initialize the map annotation view in delegate method(`-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation`) of map view.

Comment: so do you mean i should initialize the above delegate method in newmapviewcontroller?