# How Do I Add Custom Button/MapPin to MKAnnotation?

Tags: iphone, uibutton, mapkit, customization, mkannotation

I'm a noob to iphone development and i'm trying to add a custom button to an annotation callout.  I have no problems adding a regular button to rightCalloutAccessoryView, but it's just not working for custom style.  My image size is 32 x 32. I also want to add a custom map pin following this stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699171/how-do-i-add-custom-pins-to-the-iphone-mapkit) Any help is greatly appreciated.

MY CODE

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
// Define your reuse identifier.
static NSString *identifier = @"MapPoint";   

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MapPoint class]]) {
    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (annotationView == nil) {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    } else {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    annotationView.enabled = YES;
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annotationView.animatesDrop = YES;
    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"];

    UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    //UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [rightButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"phony2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rightButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(showDetails:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

    return annotationView;
}
return nil;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

```
 [rightButton addTarget:self
                action:@selector(showDetails:)
```

Remove this line 
and set frame of the button

```
[rightButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,32,32)];
```

and get the tap action from the degate method

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control;
```

where you get the annotation view.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I tried your suggestion but I'm still not having any luck.

Comment: @B. Money: You have to be more specific that "not having any luck".