# Custom Pin in Mapkit

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

I am primarily a JAVA programmer but took on a bus tracker project for the iPhone, so I am not very comfortable with this yet. Please forgive any noobish mistakes. The following code is how it was when I got pins to work. Any changes I made to attempt showing images has been removed.

```
#import "UICBus_FirstViewController.h"

@interface UICBus_FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation UICBus_FirstViewController
@synthesize timer;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
    zoomLocation.latitude = 41.869271;
    zoomLocation.longitude= -87.666436;
    // 2
    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, 0.85*METERS_PER_MILE, 0.85*METERS_PER_MILE);
    // 3
    MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [__mapView regionThatFits:viewRegion];
    // 4
    [__mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];

    CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
    frame.size.height = frame.size.height - 40;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self initRoutes];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 5 target:self selector:@selector(updateLocations) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
}

- (void)updateLocations {
    [self updateBuses];
    [self._mapView removeAnnotations:_Anns];
    _Anns = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < _Buses.count; i++){
        UICBus_Bus *Temp = _Buses[i];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D ctrpoint;
        ctrpoint.latitude = [Temp.getLat floatValue];
        ctrpoint.longitude = [Temp.getLon floatValue];
        MKAnnotation *addAnnotation = [[MKAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:Temp.getMac andCoordinate:ctrpoint];
        [_Anns addObject:addAnnotation];
    }
    [self._mapView addAnnotations:_Anns];
}


// ********************** Still need to add code to determine if bus is active or not **********************

- (void)updateBuses {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://bus.uic.edu/api/latest"];
    NSData *content = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError *JSONe;
    _BusesInput = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:content options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&JSONe];
    _Buses = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UICBus_Bus *Temp;

    if(_BusesInput.count < 1){
        NSLog(@"No Buses Found/Empty JSON");
    }else{
        for (NSString* key in _BusesInput){
            Temp = [[UICBus_Bus alloc] init:[_BusesInput objectForKey:key]];
            [_Buses addObject:Temp];
        }
    }


}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views{
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [views objectAtIndex:0];
    id <MKAnnotation> mp = [annotationView annotation];
    [mv selectAnnotation:mp animated:YES];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self set_mapView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
@end
```

So, can I get this code to display a custom pin or do I need to rework it? and how?

Comment: Did any of the solutions you looked at implement the viewForAnnotation delegate method and set the view's image property?  If you tried that and it didn't work, show that code and explain what happens or doesn't happen.

Comment: An unrelated point: It seems you've created a custom class named `MKAnnotation` for your annotation objects (code says `MKAnnotation *addAnnotation...`).  [`MKAnnotation` is also the name of the MapKit annotation protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).  I don't recommend using that same name for your custom class.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly work with didAddAnnotationViews method and didSelectAnnotation possibly while displaying and selecting custom image resp.
 I found this link to help you best with [How do I add custom pins to the iPhone MapKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699171/how-do-i-add-custom-pins-to-the-iphone-mapkit?rq=1)
Hope this helps.